# Spark kills the jobs when reach the filter function, error spark requesting executors is only supported in coarse-grained mode

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I am completely new in pyspark, and I stuck in a problem. I am trying to read a table from hive and make data frames of a specific column attributes report_d which is bigint(each row is an array of bigint)

`[20171101,20180501,20180501,20180601]            [20171001,20140901,20180501,20170901]
[20180501,20180501,20180501]
[20180601]
[20171101,20180501,20180501,20180601]   [20171001,20140901,20180501,20180501,20180501,20170901]
[20171101,20180501,20180501,20180501, 20180501, 20180501,20180601]   [20171001,20140901,20180501,20170901]`

and I want to find the number of months between this column and date which is an int. when I try to use some python function I Anyone can help ?

`sc = SparkContext("local", "monthDif")
   sqlContext= HiveContext(sc) 
   df=sqlContext.sql("select report_d from hive_table where date = 20180930")`

```
def monthDiff(df):
year = [int(val)/10000 for val in df]
month = [int(val % 10000)/100 for val in df]
day = [int(val)%100 for val in df]
yy = 2018
mm = 06
yyDif = [int(abs(val - yy)) for val in year]
mmDif = [int(val -mm) for val in month ]
countyytomm = [int(val) * 12 for val in yyDif]
return list(map(add,countyytomm, mmDif))
myudf = udf(monthDiff)
newdf = df.withColumn("monthDiff", myudf(df['report_d']))
filteredDf = newdf.filter(newdf['monthDiff']>24)`
```

I am using the above udf, but I get error when it reaches to the filter. Anyone can help? I am using Spark 1.6.0

Comment: Hi, Can you post the error message that you get.

Comment: Hi, u cannot resolve 'newdf' given input columns: [reported_d]

Comment: Did you resolve?